# Proper equality of GPathResults

Tags: groovy, equals, xmlslurper

I need to traverse through a XML and distinguish elments based on their parents. I use Groovy and XmlSlurper.

I know that the GPathResults implements equals() as equality of text() nodes only. Sadly, thats not usable in my case.

Using cmp via is() seems to be pointless since every time you get new results object. I'm a newb in Groovy, so I don't feel like overloading the equals() method.

In this case I'd like to distinguish between those  elements by their parent(). Let's say I got GPathResults of element 'b' stored in a variable. **How can I get that particular element 'a' "which got that stored element 'b' as its NEAREST parent"?**

```
          def xml = ''' <root>
                    <a type="1"/>

                    <a type="2"/>

                    <b>
                        <a type="1"/>
                    </b>
                </root>
    '''.trim()

    def slurper = new XmlSlurper(false, false).parseText(xml)

    def myParticularB = slurper.b

    def wantedA = slurper.depthFirst().find { seg ->
        seg.name() == 'a' && seg.@type == '1' && seg.parent() == myParticularB
    }

    assert (wantedA.parent().name() == 'b') == true
```

I'm sorry if I overlooked something obvious.

//A corner case

```
                  <root>
                    <a type="1"/>

                    <a type="2"/>

                    <b>
                        <a type="1"/>

                        <b>
                           <a type="1"/>

                           <b>
                              <a type="1"/>
                           </b>
                        </b>
                    </b>
                </root>
```

Comment: Nice question but a bit unclear. Could please clarify on what exactly isn't working?

Comment: Thanks, made the question a bit clearer.

Comment: Still not sure what you mean :-\

Comment: Maybe prepare an example with failing test/assert?

Comment: OK, added failing assertion. It finds the 1st 'a' inside the 'root' element, not in the 'b'. For obvious reasons. I'm sorry if I overlook smth.

Comment: If you know `b`, why not just search its children for `a`?

Comment: @tim_yates Yes, but there can be more 'b' here recursively. Therefore I'd get even 'a's which doesn't belong directly to their nearest parent 'b'... I forogt to mention this.

Comment: So what happens in the corner case? You only want the single `a` that is a direct child of `slurper.b`?

Comment: @tim_yates Exactly, a single `a` which is a direct child of `b` - a `b` which I specify (`slurper.b.b.b`, etc.).  I  don't know if there is a GPath expression which would help.

Comment: Doesn't replacing `slurper.depthFirst().find` with `myParticularB.children().find` do it?

Comment: Yes, it's helped. I'm getting some additional results with `*` named nodes, but it should be easy to filter them. Thanks a lot!